# org-agenda week view right-to-left Hebrew support (S-F-R-W-T-M-Sun) ordering

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, calendar, right-to-left

How can I view my week in org-agenda with the Days Backwards (Hebrew style)

`| March

| 7         | 6         | 5         | 4             | 3         | 2         | 1     |
| Shabbat   | Friday    | Thursday  | Wednesday     | Tuesday   | Monday    | Sunday    |`